# What does squared brackets around an interface name mean?

Tags: typescript

By pure accident I noted the following code and noticed that TypeScript considered it as valid:

```js
interface AnInterface {
  foobar: string
} 
interface AnotherInterface {
  wtf: [AnInterface]
}
```

But of which type exactly is `AnotherInterface['wtf']`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) with exactly one element of type `AnInterface`. Basically, it's a single-element array where the only element is of type `AnInterface`.